# Aggregate average

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I want to aggregate the average of a collection times the amount.
These are example documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb82e"),
    item: 555,
    amount: 1,
    priceEach: 100000
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb830"),
    item: 384,
    amount: 2,
    priceEach: 70000
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb830"),
    item: 384,
    amount: 3,
    priceEach: 50000
  }
]
```

This is my result so far:

```
[
  { _id: 366, avg: 3553248.5833333335, amount: 24 },
  { _id: 367, avg: 13565500, amount: 2 },
  { _id: 533, avg: 4286751.2, amount: 11 },
  { _id: 555, avg: 4718763.357142857, amount: 22 },
  { _id: 273, avg: 11000, amount: 57 },
  { _id: 283, avg: 23882000, amount: 8 },
  { _id: 370, avg: 4000000, amount: 2 }
]
```

The problem is that I do not take into account how often the item is available at the price.
In this concrete example I want to calculate the average of 19 * 70000 and 10 * 50000.
My previous aggregation looks like this, but here the amount is not taken into account:

```
const res = await Log.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { user: new ObjectId('653c3906012fec5ace3e54e2'), type: 'buy' }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$item',
          avg: { $avg: '$priceEach' },
          amount: { $sum: '$amount' }
        }
      }
    ])
```

If I have item 384 2x at 70000 and 3x at 50000, I want to calculate the average of [70000, 70000, 50000, 50000, 50000].

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rSSZ1R2cbMS ?

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome. You can write an answer If u want

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cmgchess the final aggregation looks like this:

```
Log.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { user: new ObjectId('653c3906012fec5ace3e54e2'), type: 'buy' }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$item',
          totalPrice: {
            $sum: {
              $multiply: [
                '$priceEach',
                '$amount'
              ]
            }
          },
          totalAmount: {
            $sum: '$amount'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          avg: {
            $divide: [
              '$totalPrice',
              '$totalAmount'
            ]
          },
          amount: '$totalAmount'
        }
      }
    ])
```